# Unable to get past json manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner wanting to create a simple Chrome extension and every I haven't been able to get past the JSON manifest part. Chrome always raises the trailing comma error and I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried multiple manifest arrangements from the internet and none of them work. I don't understand when the commas are supposed to be used. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": 1.0,
    "name": "Hello World!", 
    "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
     ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after "icon.png", and add the missing `,` before "permissions". Use an editor that highlights syntax errors or an online JSON checker.

Comment: I am using Sublime and it doesn't show any errors when Chrome does, very frustrating.

Comment: I don't think Sublime without plugins gonna check the syntax as it's not a JavaScript IDE.